# Code not working as bookmarklet in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

here is my code

```
function ()({var dob=/\s*\d*\s*\.?\s*\d*\s*-\s*\d*\s*\.?\s*\d*\s*/;

var x=prompt("Enter data","");if (x.test(dob)){var y=x.split("-");

alert(parseFloat(y[0]));
alert(parseFloat(y[1]));}
else{alert("Not Matched");}})();
```

it takes input range as `a-b(example 4-5)` and splits its value to `a` and `b`.if a single decimal is entered it shows `Not Matched`.It works fine in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ECNFe/413/) but not working in chrome as bookmarklet.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with your regex test.

Instead of this:

```
x.test(dob)
```

Try this:

```
dob.test(x)
```

Edit: Also, you're missing the beginning opening parenthesis '(' before the function.

Comment: thanks it worked,but what is diff between these two statements.

Comment: @Satya, when you created the variable `dob`, you created it as a RegExp object (you can see this by using `typeof dob`). `dob` will now have the method `test()` and you can use it for testing the RegExp. The problem you had was the variable `x` is going to come in as a string. A string does not have the method `test()` so it won't work. See the MDN for a better explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Thank you so much.look at this coding please [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvgsg9yj/3/) .Why the else part is not working ?Please explain me.Again `if(x.match(dob)[0]==null)`this is also not working.`Not Matched`case not working in any case.Why?